# Code injection issue for class.forname in Java during Checkmarx scan

Tags: java, code-injection, checkmarx

How to resolve this code injection issue for class.forname in Java. During checkmarx scan I am facing this code injection issue, below is the sample code snippet

```java
StringBuffer xml = new StringBuffer

xml.append("<?xml version=\ "1.0\"encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>");

xml.append("<Response>");

try{
    String strpath = request.getParameter("myclass");

    If(strpath!= null){
        xml.append("<Message>"+strpath+"</Message>");

        Class cls = Class.forName(strpath);

        strpath = getLocation(cls);

        xml.append("<Path>"+strpath+"</Path>");
    }

}

catch(Exception err){

    strpath = err.getMessage();

}
```

Comment: update ```getLocation``` implementation also in your question.

Comment: getLocation implementation. String getLocation(Class cls){String name = cls.getName().replace('.','/') URL loc = cls.getResource("/"+name+".class"); File f = new File (loc.getFile()); if(f.getPath().starts with("file:")){String s = f.getPath(); in} try{ f = f.getCanonicalFile();} catch(IOExecption ioe){ ioe.printStackTrace();}}

Comment: @Priyo, instead of posting the code in the comment (which does not compile-missing return Statement), edit your question

Comment: @Priyo What do you want to do and why do you use `Class.forName()`? Please [edit] your question to include the complete issue you get from checkmarx. Also, do not write XML code by hand, use a library for that. There are too many mistakes you can make.

Answer (score 0):

For Checkmarx, you assign directly a parameter to the string "strpath without saintizing it. You need to validate the string "strpath" before using it, and Checkmarx will not seen any code injection

Comment: Thank you. I tried with validation didn't resolve this issue got same error . could you please suggest